# Is QML Ahead-Of-Time compilation possible with a Loader object?

Tags: qt, caching, qml

I am trying to enable QML's "Ahead-of-time compilation" in the hope of speeding up my screen loading times a bit. However, I'm finding that even with it enabled, it is still compiling the QML files when loading them.

i.e. if I look a the QML profiler, I still see a chunk of time used up in the "Compiling" section.

[image: QML Profiler screenshot]

e.g. 771 ms in the above screenshot.

According to the QML website, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#ahead-of-time-compilation

I need to include my QML pages as resources, add `CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler` and load the QML files using the `qrc:\\\` scheme.

Here is a snippet of my PRO file with the relevant addition:

```
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += qtquickcompiler
```

I have added the QML files to my QRC file...

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>contentloader.qml</file>
        <file>qmldir</file>

        ...

        <file>images/svg/x.svg</file>
        <file>logon/logon.qml</file>
        <file>startup/alarm.qml</file>

        ...

    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And I set the source of the `Loader` item from C++ code...

```
    qDebug() << "Emitting source changed : " << m_source;
    //Show the source qml file & display the status bar
    emit sourceChanged( m_source);
```

(qDebug outputs:

> Emitting source changed : "qrc:/logon/logon.qml"

(In my header file)

```
    Q_PROPERTY( QString source MEMBER m_source NOTIFY sourceChanged )
public:
    // etc.... 

signals:
    void sourceChanged( const QString &newSource );

private:
    QString m_source;
```

...and finally the QML file relevant code...

```
        StackView {
            id: mainContent
            anchors.fill: parent


            initialItem: Loader {
                id: contentLoader

                property int sourceCount: 0;

                source: contentHandler.source   // contentHandler is the C++ class referred to above.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked your build output? The QML compilation step is pretty obvious there and would verify that it is actually occurring in your setup and for all of the files you've specified. It's possible it may only be happening in the release configuration or something like that is going wrong. Or are you saying this is only happening when a Loader is involved?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess - Thanks I will check that when I next get a chance. I'm not saying it's only happening when a Loader is involved, but my entire application is based on the Loader so I haven't really had the opportunity to try it outside of one.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess - Not sure what I'm looking for in the build output, but there is no reference to any .qml file in it, including logon.qml (the example in my question) in either the Debug or Release configuration

Comment: I would normally suspect then that the pre-compilation is not actually happening. There is (or used to be) a checkbox under project settings for enabling it. I have no idea how that interacts with the recommended settings in the .pro file but I would check that to be sure it is set and then see if you see a difference in build output.